# SpecFlow result of the action should throw exception

Tags: c#, specflow

I m trying to write stepdefinitions for this scenario:

```
@mytag
Scenario: Open Not Available Product
    Given I have opened product what is <notavailable> in store
    When I press confirm 
    Then the result should be <exception>
```

```
[Binding]
public class OpenNotAvailableProductSteps
{
    Product product;
    Action act;

    private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public OpenNotAvailableProductSteps(ScenarioContext scenarioContext, IProductService productService)
    {
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        _productService = productService;
    }

    [Given(@"I have opened product what is (.*) in store")]
    public void GivenIHaveOpenedProductWhatIsInStore(Product prod)
    {
        product = new Product
        {
            Id = 1,
            ProductCode = "123code",
            Name = "Eye Lashes",
            Variant = null,
            Price = 10.00,
            Availability = 0,
            Description = "Good Product",
            SkuCode = "123sh12",
            SecondaryCategoryId = 1
        };
    }
    
    [When(@"I press confirm")]
    public void WhenIPressConfirm()
    {
        act = () => _productService.GetProductById(1);

    }

    [Then(@"the result should be (.*) on the screen")]
    public void ThenTheResultShouldBeOnTheScreen(string p0)
    {
        Assert.Throws<IndexOutOfRangeException>(act);
    }

}
```

How can i set a result of action = product what i created before with Availability == 0;

```
       public Product GetProductById(int id)
    {
        if(id <= 0 )
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Invalid ID");
        }
        
        var product = _productRepo.GetProductById(id);

        if (product.Availability < 5 && product.Availability > 0)
        {
            product.Availability = -1;
        }
        else if (product.Availability == 0)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Product is not available. Sold Out");
        }

        return product;
    }
```

This is method from Service.
Or maybe advice some other specFlow steps scenario and implementation.

Thanks

Comment: Since your scenario contains `<...>` tokens, it makes me think this is a scenario outline. Please include the examples table for the scenario if you have one. If you do not have an examples table, we may have stumbled across the true problem.

Comment: "Then the result should be" doesn't match any of your steps -- "the result should be (.*) on the screen" is something different. Since an exception is, well, exceptional, and your method mentions nothing about screen output, you should probably formulate that differently anyway ("then an exception of type .. should be thrown").